# CoCreateInstance failed error 80040154 in Win 2003

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2003

I got error "Failed to create an instance of ITaskService: **80040154**" when i call the function **CoCreateInstance** with **CLSID_TaskSchedule** and **IID_ITaskService**.

I am using ITaskService interface for creating the scheduled task.**Same appln works fine in Win7 but failed in Win2003**.

```
 ITaskService *pService = NULL;
hr = CoCreateInstance( CLSID_TaskScheduler,
                       NULL,
                       CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                       IID_ITaskService,
                       (void**)&pService );
```

Is this ITaskService interface support only Win7/Server 2k8 R2 OR else it support all Windows platfor?

Thanks in aadvance.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation on MSDN is usually quite reliable. For [`ITaskService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> **Minimum supported client**  Windows Vista
>
> **Minimum supported server**  Windows Server 2008

Error 80040154 is "Class not registered"